# React: Updating component state by clicking an unrelated component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to learn React by building a simple shopping website where you can add items to your cart. I have a button component at the end of each item to click and add to the cart. However, I need this button to update the state of my item-count component by incrementing it by one. The button component and item-count component are completely separate and unrelated. I tried having app.js file manage the state of the item-count component and pass a function to the button component but I failed miserably. How can I make this work?

Comment: One option is to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: Do these 2 components have a parent-child relationship?

Comment: No they do not have a parent-child relationship. I thought about this before but I don't understand how to establish that relationship if these two components are rendered on different sections of the page. I will read about lifting state up though.

Comment: Lifting state up to the closest common ancestor is one way, but could result in a lot of "prop-drilling" if there's some distance between the two components, which has become a react anti-pattern. The react [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) is the solution for a "lightweight" app state that any component *anywhere* in the sub-tree of the context provider can subscribe to the context. The context value can be just about anything, so an object with the app state and a function to update state is rather simple to implement.